# Fastest way of running SVN updates in C#.NET

Tags: c#, svn

I'm trying to run an SVN update using C#. I know of a few ways to do this, but I don't know which is best.

Now, I'll start off by defining best: I'm looking for a method which doesn't care for CPU usage, bandwidth, or RAM usage (I'll be running this on a VPS, so these are all critical normally, but in this instance I will be running the action while my game server is down). I'm basically looking for the fastest method. IE the one which takes the least time from start to finish.

The methods I'm aware of are:

Run a .bat file as a process from my console application.
Run a command using the StartParameters to change directory and update the repository.
Create or download a library which allows me to run SVN queries internally to my application.

Now, I don't know how easily it is to do the third, and I'm no expert with C#, just a hobbyist with a little free time. My code so far looks like this:

```
class ServerLoader
{
    public static Process TFS = new Process();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to XtrmJosh's control centre for TFS Console.");
        // Function generate processes
        Init();

        // Function begin process
        RunServer();

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput == "r,0")
        {
            StopServer();
            Init();
            RunServer();
        }
        else if (userInput == "s,0")
        {
            StopServer();
        }
        else if (userInput == "st,0")
        {
            Init();
            RunServer();
        }
        else if (userInput == "u,0")
        {
            StopServer();
            UpdateSVN();
            RunServer();
        }

    }

    static void UpdateSVN()
    {

    }

    static void Init()
    {
        //Initialise the TFS process
        Console.WriteLine("Initialising Process");
        TFS.StartInfo.FileName = "tfs.exe";
        Console.WriteLine("Preventing window creation");
        TFS.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Redirecting Output");
        TFS.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping shell execution");
        TFS.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    }

    static void RunServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running Server");
        TFS.Start();
    }

    static void StopServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing Process");
        TFS.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Releasing Resources");
        TFS.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Further down the line I think it's quite apparent that I intend to add a TCP Server to this code, which will listen for the commands listed and act upon them. I've had plenty of practice writing TCP server applications so I shouldn't struggle with that, but this does raise issues of how to go about certain things, and of course it may be useful to know that I will be networking anyway, so if I'm networking, it may be simpler to just use a library to update the repo.

I'll also put this out there, which SVN client do you think is the most stable for this sort of job, and if they are all equally stable, which is going to do this action quickest? FYI I'm looking at only updating 3 files, 2 are small XML documents, 1 is a large graphics based document of around 3MB in size, and will soon grow to upwards of 10MB, so speed is kinda crucial, especially as I'm running a game server, I want minimal downtime if possible...

Thanks

Comment: A bit of confusion here? TFS or SVN?

Comment: Looking to update an SVN repository, sorry if I wasn't clear. TFS is the server which I'm running.

Comment: And just to clarify some more, TFS in this instance stands for The Forgotten Server, not Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Have a look at [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) which exposes an API over SVN in C#

Comment: That looks like the kind of thing I'm after Sameer, thanks!